# Auto id in database vs Auto id through code

Tags: c++, mysql, relational-database, mariadb

I am working on an enterprise application developed in C++ and the database is mariadb. The application processes two audit files `Authentication.log` and `SytemDetails.log`.

Audit operation requires data to be inserted into two tables called `Authentication table` and `SystemDetails table`. Auto id is the **primary key** for `Authentication table` and **foreign key** in `SystemDetails table`.

`Authentication table` keeps Authentication information i.e session open, login session info and `SystemDetails` keeps details of command executed during each session.

Right now an Authid is auto generated in database, as follows:

```
Authentication :AuthID,ParentAuthID,info1,Info2....    
SystemDetails:sysid,authid,info1,info2....
```

It works as follows:

1. App insert one Authentication record insert wihtout parentauthid
2. Gets the generated auth id
3. Update parentauthid field of Authentication table
4. Finds the related system details record
5. Gets the auth id from database and insert the record in database table.

**Problem:**
DB size 200k records (Authentication table).
I found 6000 record taking more than 30 min.

After analysis, I found that step 2 and step 3 is time taking processes the database grows.

I having feeling that it is better to generate the Auth id in C++ code instead of through the database. With this change we can remove step 3 and 5.

Which is better technique to generate Auto ID for table?

Answer (score 0):

Generating unique IDs in the presence of multiple users is non-trivial, and probably requires a write to permanent storage. That's slow. A client-generated GUID would be faster.

That said, when inserting a new child record you should already know the parent ID (avoids step 3) and the system details similarly should only be inserted into the DB when Authentication record exists (avoids step 4). This is true regardless of where you generate those ID's.

Comment: ParentID and AuthID is same.ParentAuthID is there  to group record belonging to same session. ParentAuthID is not known at the time of insertion,because AuthID is generated during the insertion of record by DB.after insertion we query the authid and update the ParentAuthID with authid value.

Comment: @Chris_vr: Fix your queries, instead of adding a duplicate field. Any query that can group bu `ParentAuthID` could also be written to group by `AuthID`.

Comment: ParentAuthID  is to identify record belonging to same session thats all.My question whichn is one is better, auto Authid in generation db or auto auth id through c++ code